# The nav header print @={loginViewModel.userId} instead of the data, why?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

Hi I have an Activity with a drawer menu like the next:

**MapActivity.java**

Here setup the data binding like in other activities of the apps

```
public class MapActivity extends BaseActivity{
    private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMapBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_map);
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        binding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

**activity_map.xml**

Here ser reference to ViewModel like in other layouts of this app.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>

        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.myapp.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_map"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_map_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

**nav_header_map.xml**

And this set the reference to the LoginViewModel.userId

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:text="@={loginViewModel.userId}"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when open this activity in the nav_heade_map print "@={loginViewModel.userId}" instead of the userId.

How can resolve this for that appear the userId.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your case:

1. You don't use data binding for `nav_header_map.xml` (you don't have `<layout>` tag with view model data)
2. `NavigationView` won't inflate your `app:headerLayout` with databinding (it doesn't know how to pass the data, etc)

What you could try to do, is to get the view programatically and add your header view with proper databinding setup. Something like (it's pseudo code - didn't try it):

**nav_header_map.xml**
- add the `<layout>` tag and `<data>` with your viewModel

**MapActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMapBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_map);
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        binding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        NavHeaderMapBinding headerBinding = NavHeaderMapBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater();
        headerBinding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);  // this will add the proper data to the nav_header_map.xml

        // binding.navView is automatically generated since you have android:id="@+id/nav_view" in your xml
        binding.navView.addHeaderView(headerBinding.getRoot());
}
```

Comment: In binding.navView.addHeaderView(headerView.getRoot()); cannot find navView any idea?

Comment: check your `ActivityMapBinding` generated class, it should be there

Comment: oh and I had issue there ... `....addHeaderView(headerBinding.getRoot());` `headerBinding` instead of `headerView`

Comment: I have the next error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: view must have a tag, have a idea?

Comment: huh, I don't know about that .. I know that databinding uses (or used in past) tags for some view setting, but I'd say it should not cause problems.

Comment: I was updated my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519600/navbar-appear-2-times-when-use-databinding maybe can you help me again? thanks for all the work!